# Help finding correct headset for Focus Izalco Max Disc

Tags: headset, steerer

I have acquired a Focus Izalco Max Disc frame and forks and am having trouble finding a headset for it. The steerer bung in the fork reads 28.6mm and it looks to have a slight taper. I have read online that it's a 1 1/8 -> 1 1/4 inch but the headset I have purchased doesn't fit (FSA no53).

The headtube of the frame measures ~42.5mm diameter at the top and ~47mm diameter at the bottom.

I tried the Cane Creek headset finder but it doesn't have my frame model in its database and can't identify any headset models that fit the dimensions I enter.

I have a feeling an FSA Orbit C-33 might be a fit but I can't find any material online to back this up aside from the fact it's one of the few tapered headsets with a 1-1/4" lower bearing.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think a picture of the head tube would be useful because head tubes come in straight and tapered form.

Comment: Posted, it is tapered as described in the dimensions. It seems there is little standardization with headsets - they some in all sorts of varieties

Comment: Just take it to a shop. Assuming its an authentic frame, its an expensive bit of kit. And even if it is fake, you likely don't have the tools to install a headset at home anyway.

Comment: That will be my next port of call. I'm very sure it's a genuine frame - I paid a lot for it from a proper bike shop and it has all the appropriate stickers, serial numbers etc. It's an integrated headset so no tools beyond an allen key and some grease are needed to install it. It's about getting one that's the right size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.bunnyhop.de/de/fahrradrahmen/road/focus-izalco-max-disc-ag2r-frameset-20175?info=37066) listing has it down as an Orbit C33 SL ACB.

I can't read German beyond getting the gist, but that looks to confirm your suspicions.

I believe the SL and ACB are just the materials / tier of product and C33 is size.

Comment: It specifically says _FSA Orbit C33 SL ACB_. You might want to incorporate that - just in case the link goes stale.

Comment: Thanks! I have ordered one of those - if it fits I will return here and mark your answer correct. As @ChristianLindig says - it is definitely worth mentioning the entire part name as these cycling shop links go stale very fast.

Comment: I can confirm that the FSA Orbit C33 I ordered fits

Comment: @ChristianLindig, I'm pretty sure the SL and ACB are the materials and C33 is the size. I'll add it for the sake of completeness.